# export dfSummary into latex

Tags: r, latex, summarytools

I have a dataset consist of factors and numeric and I want to export  view(dfSummary(mtcars)) in my latex is it possible? many thanks in advance

```
library(summarytools)
data("mtcars")
view(dfSummary(mtcars))
```

this is not working `xtable(dfSummary(mtcars))`

Comment: See https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools, section 6 about the PDF issue. Seems like you would have to go through conversion of the html file (e.g. with wkhtmltopdf) and import into LaTeX.

Comment: That's right @user12728748. For now this is the best approach for creating pdfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RStudio, if you create an *Rmarkdown* document, with *pdf* as output format, you can go in **Output Options > Advanced > Keep tex source file used to produce PDF**.

[image: RStudio-Markdown-Document-Options]

When using *png* images (with `style="grid"` and specified `tmp.img.dir`), there is an alignment issue; you need to add this to the `\includegraphics` commands: `\includegraphics[valign=t]`. You can also use something like `\raisebox{0.5\height}` if the image appears too low in its table cell.